# sql count and order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database and two commands to display the same thing

```
SELECT name, score
FROM sm_easyrank
ORDER BY score DESC, name ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

This selects the players ordered by score, and if two players has the same score, they will be order by name.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM sm_easyrank
WHERE score >= (SELECT (score)
                FROM sm_easyrank
                WHERE steamid = '%s'
               )
```

This will count how many players are before me.

The problem is: I have a position in first order, and another in second (if i have the same score with someone else). I wanna order in second players with same score by name.

sm_easyrank is the table name

score is a column with scores (number column)
steamid is a unique id
name is a column with name of the people
sorry for my english!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you want to return.  And that is `steamid` and how is that related to `name`?

Comment: i edited, i dont know if now is good, i'm newest here

Comment: So do you want find the names and scores of all the people scoring higher than you?

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

Comment: yes, but in order like in first select

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want using a `JOIN` and conditions that include both the score and name:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM sm_easyrank s JOIN
     sm_easyrank s2
     ON s2.steamid = '%s' AND
        (s.score > s2.score OR
         s.score = s2.score AND s.name <= s2.name
        );
```

Comment: this works, thanks very much. next time i will be more explicit. i'm new here  and i don't know how things works here